# Launch Firefox using Selenium

Tags: maven, selenium, firefox

I am Trying to lunch Firefox and do a simple search on Google but  i am  only able to launch the Firefox. what should be  edit in the code to run it smooth?I am Using Firefox Quantum  57 which runs using maven dependencies.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class FirefoxLaunch
{
    @Test
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        WebDriver driver;
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        element.sendKeys("FirefoxDriver Search Function");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which framework are you using `JUnit` or `TestNG`?

Comment: Junit how ever i need to  test the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While working with:

- *Selenium v3.x* [java](/questions/tagged/java) clients
- *Firefox Quantum v70.x*

You need to download the [geckodriver](/questions/tagged/geckodriver) binary from this [link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and save it in your system and then provide the absolute path of *GeckoDriver* binary through `System.setProperty()` line as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Comment: Hi Debanjan,
Thank you  very much,  now it's working

Comment: Debanjan, just a side question, 
I was able to launch the FF browser  using but could not  do a simple search  editing the code to ("webdriver.firefox.marionette"), How ever gecko driver  did n't work

Comment: wanted to share an update with this
adding a page load time out with an exception handling did work without an issue.